# Why should we add public key to authorized keys, when private key is used as identity file for SFTP transfer using JSch

Tags: ssh, jsch, private-key, public-key

When we need to add public key to authorized keys, why is that we are using identity file authentication with private key for sftp transfer

```java
Session session = null;
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();        
try
{
    session = jsch.getSession( targetUserId, targetHost, targetPort );
    session.setConfig( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );

    if( identityFile != null )
    {
        jsch.addIdentity( identityFile );
    }

    if( targetPassword != null )
    {
        session.setPassword( targetPassword );
    }

    session.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH public key authentication is uses asymmetric encryption.

You have a key pair, where one of the keys is called private (identity) and the other public. What you encrypt with the private key can be decrypted with the public key and vice versa. So the server needs to posses your public key to be able to decrypt the SSH traffic coming from you (the JSch SSH client).

Read about [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).